# Django REST Framework -- static alias for {pk} url

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

There's a standard ViewSet, and urls are like: /api/users/ and /api/users/{pk}/. I'd like to have /api/users/me/ that behaves exactly like detail view accessed by pk (so /api/users/me/ behaves like /api/users/5/ if your user id is 5).

I've tried this:

```
def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    if kwargs.get('pk') == 'me' and request.user:
        kwargs['pk'] = request.user.pk

    return super(UserViewSet, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

And, it works perfectly (all HTTP methods) with SessionAuthentication but not with TokenAuthentication. With TokenAuthentication, it returns:

```
curl -H "Authorization: Token f14b876aa54ebb7679330b88ea1c5b5ea4d693e9" http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/users/me/
{"detail":"Not found."}
```

And, dispatch() is not even executed, so something earlier must be blocking it. Other views (eg. /api/users/) work correctly. What may be the cause, how to debug this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using something more elegant:

```
def get_object(self):
    if self.kwargs['pk'] == 'me':
        return self.request.user
    else:
        return super().get_object()
```

Why the original idea works with SessionAuthentication but not with TokenAuthentication is still a mystery.